# JPA/Hibernate: how to re-use JPQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I have a somewhat complicated `@NamedQuery` that queries the following entity:

```
@Entity
class Employee {
  @Id
  String id;

  LocalDate dateOfBirth;

  String companyId;
}
```

It includes several joins and a whole bunch of where conditions to check if a user can access that `Employee` (they can access it if they work for the same company, or if the user works for a company that has a contract with the `Employee`'s company, etc.)

I would like to reuse that query for searches (based on `companyId` or a range of `dateOfBirth`s) and for fetching the `Employee` by its `id`. Is there a way to do that, or do I need to resort to a Criteria query or something similar?

(I'm using Quarkus with Panache if that makes it easier/harder)

Edit: I also considered using a `@Filter` annotation on the entity but (from the Hibernate docs):

> Filters apply to entity queries, but not to direct fetching. Therefore, in the following example, the filter is not taken into consideration when fetching an entity from the Persistence Context.

Of course I don't want to accidentally forget the authorization check if I happen to use `EntityManager.find`...

Comment: You would forget the same if you wouldn't use a named query. So even with only `@NamedQuery` you would have the same problem.

Comment: Regarding "So even with only @NamedQuery you would have the same problem." The issue is that even if you remembered to activate the `@Filter`, the filter will (silently) not be applied when you use `EntityManager.find`. I find that so misleading to be dangerous (to my use case).

Comment: But that doesn't change if you forget to use your `@NamedQuery` and use  `find`. so in both situations nothing will be filtered. But to my knowledge there is no reuse of `@NamedQuery`, the only thing you could do (and which might or might not work) is to pull out the check part and put that into a constant which you append to each query manually. But the risk is the same. The filter could be activated with AOP so you cannot forget it.